# Can I vertex paint on top of procedural texture?

Tags: node-editor, texture-painting, sculpting, vertex-paint

can I vertex paint on to of procedural texture? I just start getting into the texture/coloring of models, I've spent a lot of time learning the modeling aspect of blender. This is model isn't an efficient one, it hasn't been retopologized or anything like that. I'm trying to get all the details working.

[image]

Comment: you mean texture painting? It's different from vertex painting

Comment: Can I texture paint on top of the procedural node stuff?

Comment: You can mix an image texture with other nodes, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most definitely you can mix your vertex paint and your texture paint together in your material node tree and preview the result - here is Suzanne with some default Dirty Vertex Paint and a flat brown image texture slot mixed with a color mix node set to 'Overlay'  - left window is the vertex dirt, right window is the combined shading result.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, an olive branch to a new rabbit hole. I'm going to ask another question.  This one will be kind of in regards to making UV bump map.